# Can I take the theory exam in English for driving license in Portugal?

Tags: usa, driving-license, freelance, driving, portugal

Can I take the theory exam in English for driving license in Portugal?

Comment: If you have a UK driving licence you can use it until it expires. You just have to register it. See https://www.gov.uk/living-in-portugal#driving-licences-and-vehicles. With whether you can take the test in English. I guess you could try calling the office up to see?

Answer (score 5):

According to this [site](http://portugal.angloinfo.com/transport/driving-licences/driving-tests/), the exam is in Portuguese but you can get assistance from an interpreter. Here is an excerpt and the emphasis is mine:

> The theory test for a Category B licence contains 30 questions to be answered in 35 minutes 
>   of which 27 must be correct. There is also an oral Technical Test which lasts 50 minutes. 
>   **If the candidate is foreign, and does not have sufficient knowledge of Portuguese an 
>   Embassy or Consulate accredited interpreter may be taken to the exam**.